# Eventmachine start_tcp_server no acceptor - port is in use or requires root privileges (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost, eventmachine

I haven't been able to run my local server for 3 days now. Restarting my computer doesn't help. A couple of time, after trying repeatedly about 40-50 times, it randomly worked - I can't figure out why. I tried a different port once and that worked, but since then, no port works. Every time I try to run my rails server I get this.

```
/Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.5/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.5/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_server'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:55:in `block in start'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.5/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.5/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.5/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

When I run `ps aux | grep rails` I get this output:

```
colmtuite        6422   0.0  0.0  2441988    668 s002  S+    2:44am   0:00.00 grep rails
```

When I run `ps aux | grep ruby` I get this output:

```
colmtuite       13305   0.0  0.0  2423356    200 s000  R+    8:15pm   0:00.00 grep ruby
```

Are my ports closed for some reason?

Comment: What happens if you run it w/`sudo`?

Comment: Do you mean run 'sudo ps aux | grep rails'? I got this output: colmtuite       17258   0.0  0.0  2450180    672 s000  S+    1:53am   0:00.00 grep rails

Comment: For 'sudo ps aux | grep ruby' I got this output: colmtuite       17286   0.0  0.0  2441988    676 s000  S+    1:55am   0:00.00 grep ruby

Comment: No, I meant to try running your local server w/the `sudo` command :) Then you will know if the problem is related to root privileges or the port being in use.

Comment: I got this output: https://gist.github.com/colmtuite/9c7e11a17f51f273c0fe

Comment: When I run 'gem list', it lists 'railties (4.2.0)' though....

Comment: try running "bundle update" to get latest gems, and try again.

Comment: Tried that mate, no change....

Answer (score 13):

I also had same problem

This works for me

```
$ ps ax | grep rails
```

then kill process using process id

```
$ kill -9 [process Id]
```

..

Example

```
$ kill -9 20496
```

..

start server again