# Rails Thin server running but can't connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, thin

When I start my server I get this output:
[image]

But I can't connect to the server.

[image]

Comment: What url are you using ?

Comment: URL is localhost:3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add port number 3000 at the end of url, for example:

```
 localhost:3000

 or

 127.0.0.1:3000
```

Comment: I'm already on localhost:3000. I asked this question which my provide more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519844/eventmachine-start-tcp-server-no-acceptor-port-is-in-use-or-requires-root-priv

Comment: 127.0.0.1:3000 works now. But localhost:3000 doesn't work. I've been using localhost: 3000 for years. Any idea why it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Seems your dns resolution not working properly, you can workaround it by adding this line to /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1   localhost